# Simple math with decimals in PHP

Tags: php, math, simplexml, decimal

This is killing me! I've never had so much trouble and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

If I have a number, say 2.32, and I want to do math with it it won't work out. The very simplest example:

```
$income = $commission; //Commission is 2.32, retrieved from XML
echo "income: $income<br>";
$income100 = $income*100;
echo "income100: $income100<br>";
```

The result I get is:

```
income: 2.32
income100: 200
```

How can I use a decimal number accurately with math without it changing it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: $income = (float) $commission; Likely a simpleXML object

Comment: @bigman how should then ``$income*100`` work ?

Comment: @bigman: Why would you cast it as a `string` so that it hopefully converts to `float`... just cast it as a `float`

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize I made it a string, meant to throw a float. Brain fart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign `$income` in the following manner to get rid of the underlying `SimpleXMLElement`:

```
$income = (float) $commission;
```

[Example of what happens when you don't](http://codepad.org/katxKdXK):

```
$x = simplexml_load_string("<a>2.4</a>");
echo $x * 100; // output:  200
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides using floats as Tim said, also make sure to use the [BC Math](http://php.net/bcmath) functions when performing arithmetic operation on floating point numbers. Specifically [bcmul()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php):

`$income100 = bcmul($income, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with floating-point numbers is that you cannot represent decimal numbers with them (unless it can be written as `a/b` for integer `a` and `b`, and even then only if `abs(a) < pow(2,52)` and `b` is a power of 2).

You may be better off using string functions to get an integer value:

```
$tmp = explode(".",$commission);
$tmp = intval($tmp[0].str_pad(substr($tmp[1],0,2),2,"0"));
```

This will split up the integer part from the decimal part, ensure the decima part is two digits long, and shove it on the end of the integer part, thus effectively multiplying the original number by 100.

Comment: No, but I wasn't trying to. There's obviously something going wrong in the conversion to a number that's resulting in the decimal being dropped, but this answer solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to cast it to a float with [floatval()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

`$income = floatval($comission)`

leave the rest of the code as is and it should work as intended.